# shortcode with $atts with strange results

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, customization

Here below a function for the presentation of 2 banners with **shortcodes + $atts** . Each of the two banners must get there own shortcode to show it. So i can place them where i want on the page.

Result I need: **[show_homepage_banner banner_id=1]** + **[show_homepage_banner banner_id=2]**

With the below code of GentlemanMax I get no results. But there are 3 records in table that match the query. Here the query result:

```
Array ( [banner_id] => 2 ) SELECT * FROM wp_rdp_banners WHERE banner_type = "1" AND end_date >= CURDATE() AND banner_id=%d LIMIT 2Array ( [banner_id] => 1 ) SELECT * FROM wp_rdp_banners WHERE banner_type = "1" AND end_date >= CURDATE() AND banner_id=%d LIMIT 2Array ( [banner_id] => 2 ) SELECT * FROM wp_rdp_banners WHERE banner_type = "1" AND end_date >= CURDATE() AND banner_id=%d LIMIT 2
```

Here the result of print_r($atts)

```
Array ( [banner_id] => 2 ) Array ( [banner_id] => 1 ) Array ( [banner_id] => 2 )
```

Here the banners in the table:

```
banner_id   banner_type picture end_date 
61  1   b1.png  22-8-2016
43  1   cblue.png   16-8-2016
60  1   b3.png  16-8-2016
```

What do I have to fix?

```
function show_homepage_banner_function($atts) {

$atts = shortcode_atts( array('banner_id' => NULL), $atts );

$content = '';
global $wpdb;

$upload_url = '';
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$target_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'];
$upload_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/banners/';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM wp_rdp_banners WHERE banner_type = "1" AND  end_date >= CURDATE()";
$query .= isset($atts['banner_id']) ? ' AND banner_id=%d' : ' ORDER BY RAND()';
$query .= ' LIMIT 2';
$ban= $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query, $atts['banner_id']));

if(count($result)) {
     $content = '<div class="rdp-banner-1"><a href="'.$ban->banner_link.'"><img src="'.$upload_url.$ban->picture.'" ></a></div>';                
}
return $content;
```

}

```
add_shortcode('show_homepage_banner', 'show_homepage_banner_function');
```

Comment: Both of your functions have the same name?

Comment: changed but no result as needed

Comment: Can you update the above as well? Are you passing the atts from one function to the other?

Comment: I have no experience with this function. Not mines. But need to split the results of the query into 2 different [shortcodes] so I can place the images at different positions on the site. If you can help me fixing the function(s) would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you have above don't use the id att at all.  This might be what you want, but I'm not 100% sure what you're going for.

```
function show_homepage_banner_function($atts) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array('id' => NULL), $atts );

    $content = '';
    global $wpdb;

    $upload_url = '';
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $target_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'];
    $upload_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/banners/';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}banners WHERE banner_type = "1" AND  end_date >= CURDATE()";
    $query .= isset($atts['id']) ? ' AND id=%d' : ' ORDER BY RAND()';
    $query .= ' LIMIT 1';
    $ban= $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query, $atts['id']));

    if(count($result)) {
         $content = '<div class="rdp-banner-1"><a href="'.$ban->banner_link.'"><img src="'.$upload_url.$ban->picture.'" ></a></div>';                
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Note, I set this up to pick a random banner if no id is specified.  I also assumed that the id column in the database is literally "id".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. I added it in my question be course I did not get any banner with [show_homepage_banner banner_id=1] + [show_homepage_banner banner_id=2]. I have included the print_r() to show what is going on. Maybe you see the problem.